# Cocos2d: Box2d body won´t react on force (Ghetto Birds-system)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I´ve been trying to implementing the [Ghetto Birds](https://github.com/robotron2084/GhettoBirds) slingshot system, got it up and running to the point where the pull feedback (the path of dots to show power/direction) updates after touch position, but sadly the ball won´t fly when I release. This is what happens(speaking code) when I release the pull:

```
1.applyForce-method gets called, this contains these operations:
  -> Calls a method that creates a box2d body of the ball sprite. 
  -> Calculates the force to be applied on the ball. 
  -> Applies the force on the ball.
```

I´ve checked that all these methods actually gets called during runtime.

So, the body is created, the force is applied to that body, but it won´t move. Am I missing a required step here?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I´m using cocos2d 2.0 for what it´s worth!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check here.

1. Make sure the body is a dynamic body.  Otherwise it won't respond to forces.
2. Forces should be applied continuously because they may be cleared after each time step.  So the `body->ApplyForce()` should be in a scheduled method that is called each time step.  However, from what you're describing it might be better to use `body->ApplyLinearImpulse()`.  This only gets applied once but will give your object enough of a "kick" to launch it into motion.